# Submitting Values From a Jquery Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, post

Hey guys I have this code here for a jquery slider. I want to take the value of the slider out and use an http post method to submit the value to a database. I have a processing form which I used successfully for textboxes and radio buttons. I was hoping to save the value of the slider in a hidden field and just post it. I know this gets the value from the slider.

```
    var selection = $( ".selector" ).slider( "value" );
```

Now how can I add this into the value in this submit form?

```
    <input type='hidden' class="mainForm" id="fieldBox_5" name="field_5" value=selection>
```

This is my whole code.

```
    <<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Slider bound to select</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var select = $( "#minbeds" );
    var slider = $( "<div id='slider'></div>" ).insertAfter( select ).slider({
      min: 1,
      max: 10,
      range: "min",
      value: select[ 0 ].selectedIndex + 1,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        select[ 0 ].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
      }
    });
    $( "#minbeds" ).change(function() {
      slider.slider( "value", this.selectedIndex + 1 );
    });
  });
  var selection = $( ".selector" ).slider( "value" );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="mainForm_1" class="MainForm" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data action=processorss.php onSubmit="return validatePage1();">



  <label for="minbeds" class="mainForm">Rate Your Prefence for Fish 1-10</label>
 <select name="minbeds" id="minbeds">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
  </select>
  <li class="mainForm">



  <input type='hidden' class="mainForm" id="fieldBox_5" name="field_5" value=selection>

                    <input id="saveForm" class="mainForm" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </li>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById('fieldBox_5').value = selection;` or `$('#fieldBox_5').val(selection);` (if you prefer jQuery) just after your last JS code (in the on ready block) ah and you need to move `var selection` declaration inside the on ready method too.

Comment: Since OP is using JQuery, you could simply use `$('#fieldBox_5').val(selection);`

Comment: thanks @ochi, i think both are fine, after all jQuery is nothing more than js library (briliant though) correct.

Answer (score 1):

I added the extra code to copy the selected value (either from the dropdown or the slider) to the hidden field.  The trick is that once you got the value of the item selected, you need to copy it to the hidden field yourself.

The relevant changes are here (I am also printing it to console to verify the values, you can remove those two lines after checking it works correctly for you):

```
var selection = $("#slider").slider("value");
console.log("Slider value: " + selection);
$("#selectedNumber").val( selection );
console.log("Hidden field value: " + $("#selectedNumber").val());
```

**See demo below:**

```js
$(function() {
    var select = $("#minbeds");
    var slider = $("<div id='slider'></div>").insertAfter(select).slider({
      min: 1,
      max: 10,
      range: "min",
      value: select[0].selectedIndex + 1,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        select[0].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
        $("#selectedNumber").val( ui.value - 1 );
        console.log("Slider value: " + (ui.value - 1) );
        console.log("Hidden field value: " + $("#selectedNumber").val());              
      }
    });
  
    $("#minbeds").change(function() {
      slider.slider("value", this.selectedIndex + 1);
      var selection = $("#slider").slider("value");
      console.log("Slider value: " + selection);
      $("#selectedNumber").val( selection );
      console.log("Hidden field value: " + $("#selectedNumber").val());      
    });
  });
```

```css
#slider {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<form id="mainForm_1" class="MainForm" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data action=processorss.php onSubmit="return validatePage1();">


  <li class="mainForm">
    <label for="minbeds" class="mainForm">Rate Your Prefence for Fish 1-10</label>

    <select name="minbeds" id="minbeds">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
    </select>

    <input type='hidden' class="mainForm" id="selectedNumber" name="selectedNumber" />

    <input id="saveForm" class="mainForm" type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </li>
</form>
```